# Terminal commands

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to create an "automatic wifi hacker", but I have an issue.  When I run this line of code:

```
os.system ("airmon-ng start 'airmon1'")
```

it doesn't do what it is supposed to, and I think it's because the command is kind of running "inside" of the Python script.

What I'm looking for is a way to maybe open another terminal that's normal (as in not running a Python script) and then execute a command in that terminal.
(By the way, `airmon1` is a variable that's been assigned a value.)

Comment: `'airmon1'` is just a string, in that context, not a variable

Comment: did you check out [python sh](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/)? not necessarily specifically related to your problem, but I have had good experience with sh and terminal commands in general

Comment: `os.system ("airmon-ng start {}".format(airmon1))` will be better...

Comment: Jean-François Fabre Thanks for your answer, it worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"airmon-ng start 'airmon1'"` is a raw string. If you want to use the `airmon1` variable, as you say, then you need to insert the variable into the string, accordingly.

```
"airmon-ng start '{}'".format(airmon1)
```

or

```
"airmon-ng start '%s'" % str(airmon1)
```